# scipy.stats.levene test results analysis. Where is significance level?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I am trying to interpret the results of my `scipy.levene` test but unfortunately there is not a lot of literature out there that I can find on this.

I am testing to see if the variance of two samples is the same as they are not normally distributed. My pandas Dataframe looks like this:

```
      Plj  Psp  Phj
0     1061  773  859
1      975  870  749
2      866  841  887
3      898  789  878
4      913  742  803
...  ...  ...
7963   760  604  714
7964   845  524  767
7965   804  653  840
7966   720  539  758
7967   809  692  714
```

The columns I am looking at are `Phj` and `Plj` and my levenes test is as such:

```
var_jumps = levene(points.Phj, points.Plj)
LeveneResult(statistic=2.3966590973264372, pvalue=0.12161454551270283)
```

Clearly here the test statistic is way more than the p-value but how do I know the significance level? There is no parameter in the documentation to set this, nor is it in the result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you choose the significance level you want before hand, and then compare to the pvalue

see https://statisticsbyjim.com/glossary/significance-level/ for a good explanation

a common default is .05

therefor, in this case, since the pvalue of .12 > .05, you would not conclude that there is sufficient evidence that the two samples have different variances

Comment: A useful explanation. I'm confused as to what the test statistic is for then?

Comment: heres a somewhat helpful link: https://towardsdatascience.com/hypothesis-tests-and-p-value-a-gentle-introduction-4b52322bfc50

generally, you perform some test and get a test statistic. this test statistic is generally between -inf and inf and is assumed to follow a specific distribution (the distribution depends on which test you are running). the pvalue is basically the test statistic converted to a probability. it is computed from the test statistic, and is going to be between 0  and 1, and is the probability of rejecting the null hypothesis

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Do you know if there is any way I can obtain the critical value for significance level of 0.05 so that I can compare to the test statistic?

Comment: not off top of head. why do you want to do that, as opposed to comparing the pvalue to .05? (they are equivalent)

Comment: Lecturer is picky about p-values for some reason, no idea why.

Comment: from wiki, it appears for levenes test the test statistic is f-distributed (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levene%27s_test). so you can use that with relevant degrees of freedom